# db2 INSERT INTO target table from multiple source tables

Tags: sql, db2, insert-into

I have two source tables, `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`

They each have one column of data I'd like to grab, and each have the exact same number of rows and I'd like to match them up in a third table pair-wise like so:

```
Column_A | Column_B
    Val1 | ValA
    Val2 | ValB
    Val3 | ValC
    Val4 | ValD
```

When using this syntax the data in `Table_3` doesn't match up, the rows in `Column_B` are being populated with missing fields instead of lining up next to the `Column_A` values.

```
INSERT INTO Table_3 (Column_A)
SELECT Column_A FROM Table_1;
INSERT INTO Table_3 (Column_B)
SELECT Column_A FROM Table_2;
```

Comment: Putting the columns in the select list between parentheses is totally useless.

Answer (score 2):

First, just because you have the same rows doesn't mean that you can readily combine them.  You can join them together:

```
INSERT INTO Table_3 (Column_A, Column_B)
    SELECT t1.Column_A, t2.Column_B
    FROM Table_1 t1 JOIN
         Table_2 t2
         ON t1.?? = t2.??
```

Your question does not clarify what the `JOIN` keys should be.

If you don't have `JOIN` keys but want arbitrary pairs, you can do use `row_number()` to assign a `join` key:

```
INSERT INTO Table_3 (Column_A, Column_B)
    SELECT t1.Column_A, t2.Column_B
    FROM (SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column_A) as seqnum Table_1 t1
         ) JOIN
         (SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column_B) as seqnum Table_2 t2
         ) t2
         ON t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks, as I don't have a join key this works great.